# Is there a way to implicitly convert an implicit parameter in Scala?

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, lift, implicit-conversion

Is there a way to make this work (Scala 2.8.1):

```
class A
class B
def f(implicit b: B) {}
implicit val a = new A
implicit def aToB(a: A) = new B
f(a) // works ok
f // error: could not find implicit value for parameter b: B
```

Actually my problem is with Lift's (2.2) dependency injection, i'm trying to convert Vendor[T] to T and implicitly require it in a class constructor without adding imports after each val:

```
object DependencyFactory extends Factory {
  implicit def vendorToVal[T](vendor: Vendor[T]): T = vendor.vend

  implicit val db = new FactoryMaker[DbAccess](Model) {}
  //uncommenting the following line makes it work, but can we avoid it? 
  //import db._
  implicit val userStore = new FactoryMaker[UserStore](new UserStore) {}
}
```

Where `UserStore` is:

```
class UserStore(implicit db: DbAccess)
```

Am i doing something wrong?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to *Easy Angel* for answering the first part. But it doesn't solve my Lift DI problem because it turns out that there is an opposite conversion in scope (from T to Vendor[T]) and having those both leads to 'error: diverging implicit expansion'.

Can it be solved?

**UPDATE2**

Wow one more problem after previous: having a conversion from some Container[T] to T with implicit instance of Container[U] in scope and a function with implicit parameter U leads to 'diverging implicit expansion' too:

```
class A
case class Vendor[T](v: T)
def f(implicit a: A) {}
implicit val vendor = Vendor(new A)
implicit def vendorToVal[T](implicit v: Vendor[T]) = v.v
f
```

Any hints?

Comment: About *Update2*... I tried to run compiler with `-Xlog-implicits` option and it seems to me, that compiler is not able to infer T correctly. For example if you will write `implicit def vendorToVal(implicit v: Vendor[A]): A = v.v` it will compile. But still I'm not sure... I would be also happy to know the reason why it does not compile. I think this deserves question on it's own. So I advise you to create new question with `Update2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You almost made it. You only need to declare `a` implicit:

```
implicit def aToB(implicit a: A) = new B
```

In this case compiler tries to find some implicit `B` for the first implicit argument of `f` and it finds `aToB`. Than compiler ties to satisfy `aToB`'s requirement (`implicit a: A`) and finds your `implicit val a`.

Comment: Thanks, it works for my simple example, but leads to 'diverging implicit expansion' in Lift's case. Let's see if anything can be done there...

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the best and most concise solution to this problem. But it was interesting for me whether it's technically possible to achieve what you want. I tried to reproduce all involved classes as close as possible without Lift... and here is one of the possible solutions using view bounds:

```
class DbAccess
class UserStore[T](implicit db: T, ev: T => DbAccess)

class Vendor[T] (val vend: T)
class FactoryMaker[T] (vend: T) extends Vendor[T](vend)

implicit def vendorToVal[T](vendor: Vendor[T]) = vendor.vend

implicit val db: Vendor[DbAccess] = new FactoryMaker[DbAccess](new DbAccess) {}
implicit val userStore = new FactoryMaker[UserStore[Vendor[DbAccess]]](new UserStore) {}
```

In this case `UserStore` knows fact, that `T` is not `DbAccess`, but it also knows that `T` can be viewed and used as `T`.

---

#### Edit

About your second example (in comment). This simple workaround comes to my mind:

```
class A
class B
trait HighPrio

def f(implicit b: B) {}

implicit val a = new A with HighPrio

implicit def aToB(implicit a: A with HighPrio) = new B;
implicit def bToA(implicit b: B) = new A;

f
```

... not sure whether it will work in your Lift case.

Comment: The problem is this single line `implicit def vendorToVal[T](vendor: Vendor[T]) = vendor.vend` leads to 'diverging implicit expansion' on **any** implicit parameter because there is the opposite conversion (from T to Vendor[T]) in scope and seems like i can't get rid of it.

Comment: In other words the situation is like this: `class A; class B; def f(implicit b: B) {}; implicit val a = new A; implicit def aToB(implicit a: A) = new B; implicit def bToA(implicit b: B) = new A; f`

Comment: Thanks again for trying to help, but there is one more thing going on, which can be illustrated by this: `class A; case class Vendor[T](v: T); def f(implicit a: A) {}; implicit val vendor = Vendor(new A); implicit def vendorToVal[T](implicit v: Vendor[T]) = v.v; f`