# Implicit conversion of a generic container for an implicit parameter in Scala

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, lift, implicit-conversion

Is there a way to make this work? (Scala 2.8.1)

```
class A
def f(implicit a: A) = 0

class Vendor[T](val v: T)
implicit val vendor = new Vendor(new A)
implicit def vendorToVal[T](implicit v: Vendor[T]) = v.v
f
```

The error is: 'diverging implicit expansion for type A starting with method vendorToVal'

This is related to Lift 2.2 dependency injection, the real code looks like this:

```
class UserStore(implicit db: DbAccess)
object DependencyFactory extends Factory {
  implicit val db = new FactoryMaker[DbAccess](Model) {}
  import db._ // implicit conversion would allow to remove this import

  implicit val userStore = new FactoryMaker[UserStore](new UserStore) {}
}
```

This question is related to: [Is there a way to implicitly convert an implicit parameter in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204928/is-there-a-way-to-implicitly-convert-an-implicit-parameter-in-scala)

Comment: My final solution to the Lift DI problem is to use imports instead of implicit arguments for dependencies. Details: http://scala-notes.blogspot.com/2011/03/dependency-injection-with-lift.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused with `vendorToVal` method - I observed the same behavior many times, when I've been using implicit parameters in implicit type-parametrized methods. Unfortunately, I've found no simple and elegant glue in 2.8._.

Some interesting threads, related to the topic:

1. http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-Why-is-this-a-diverging-implicit-td1998156.html
2. http://www.scala-lang.org/node/6847

Answer (score 1):

In Scala 2.9 trunk, you can do this:

```
scala> class A
defined class A

scala> def f(implicit a: A) = 0
f: (implicit a: A)Int

scala> 

scala> class Vendor[T](val v: T)
defined class Vendor

scala> implicit def value[T: Vendor] = implicitly[Vendor[T]].v
value: [T](implicit evidence$1: Vendor[T])T

scala> implicit val vendor = new Vendor(new A)
vendor: Vendor[A] = Vendor@bbb2d0

scala> f
res0: Int = 0
```

Calling `f` will search for a value of type `A`, and find the implicit `value[A]`, which requires an evidence parameter of type `Vendor[A]`. It resolves this evidence parameter to `vendor`.

I don't think implicits were that powerful in 2.8.1.

Comment: In my version of 2.9.0 it breaks, when I add an implicit `Vendor` for another class to the same context: `class B; implicit val vendor_b = new Vendor(new B)`

Comment: True. In that case, I guess one could still write `f(value[A])`, but that beats the meaning..